# Linear stability of a fixed point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lipshitz continuous such that $f(0)=0$. Let $$x'=y\\
y'=-f(x)$$

Determine whether the point $(0,0)$ is stable or asymptotically stable or unstable as a function of $f(x)$.

My attempt:

I feel that I can not linearize this system since $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, so I would appreciate any help od hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to $x'' = -f(x)$.  This obeys the energy equation
$$ \tfrac12 (x')^2 + F(x) = \text{constant} $$
where $F$, the potential energy, is the anti-derivative of $f$.  By looking at a graph of $F$ you can get an idea of the many and varied things behaviors a solution can have near $x = 0$.  For example, think about $F(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$.

If you think long and hard in this direction, I think you will be able to answer your question even if $f$ isn't differentiable.